2DFF synchronizer output was determined to be a clock by timing analyzer
I'm the newbie in FPGA.
I want to design a frequency counter, so the design will involved some CDC problem.
Therefore, I used FIFO (I use the Quartus FIFO IP) and 2DFF synchronizer in my design.
Below is my RTL picture:

More information for the 2DFF synchronizer :

OK, here comes the problem.
When I use Timing Analyzer to deal with the timing constraints,
the system always gives me a warning like this:

Warning (332060): Node: synchronizer:S1|DFF_SYNC:D2|Q was determined to be a clock but was found without an associated clock assignment.
Info (13166): Register FIFO_2:FIFO2|dcfifo:dcfifo_component|dcfifo_m9q1:auto_generated|altsyncram_b1b1:fifo_ram|ram_block11a10~porta_datain_reg3 is being clocked by synchronizer:S1|DFF_SYNC:D2|Q

The Node: synchronizer:S1|DFF_SYNC:D2|Q I think it shouldn't be a clock signal,
It's just a signal that I want to synchronize to the clk domain.
I used to have a previous sdc file, and in the previous sdc file, this problem didn't exist,
but after I restart a new sdc file, and do the same constraints (maybe, I  don't really sure about this ) as the previous one, this warning shows up.
Can somebody tell me what's wrong with it? And how to fix it?

The output of the synchroniser is feeding to the rdclk pin of the FIFO_1 instance, and the wrclk of FIFO_2, which then drives the clock pins of some registers or memory internally. Therefore Quartus has determined it to be a clock.
To fix it you need to disconnect the signal from the FIFO clock pins. Presumably by connecting you actual clock to the clock pins  then connecting the signal to the rdreq/wrreq pins. Though I can only speculate without knowing what the logic is supposed to do.
